# Loading external resources with CommonJS

Tags: javascript, amd, commonjs

I don't get it how to load external resources with CommonJS modules.

RequireJS provides shim configs like:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'facebook' : {
            export: 'FB'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug'
    }
});
```

How can I do the same with CommonJS?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is using common JS (not CommonJS) techniques:

```
function loadFacebook(callback) {
    if (typeof(FB) == 'undefined') {
        jQuery.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js",
            success: callback,
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

I'm suprised that CommonJS doesn't define any specifaction to load external resources.